# How to read the image type from an URL?

Tags: javascript, file

I encountered something very strange:

[image]

As you see the second last picture has jpg format but it's being displayed as `png` type. (This is the Network panel in Chrome.)

How can I get this `png` file type with JavaScript? (How can I get it's MIME type)?

Comment: renaming a file doesn't change its mime type; it's a png

Comment: image type from an URL? We need more information.

Comment: Are you manually getting the image in JavaScript or is it an img tag?

Comment: `FileList[n].type` if it's an upload.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check the `content-type` response header. The appropriate value is listed in the Chrome network debugger. Alternatively, you can look it up on one of the many [lists](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) on the internet.

Assuming you are using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  url: "[image url]",
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (contentType === "image/jpeg") {
      // do something with jpg
    }
    if (contentType === "image/png") {
      // do something with png
    } 
  }
});
```

If you are using plain javascript use `XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader()` in stead.

Comment: Ah, you don't have code to retrieve the image yet? I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Send a HEAD request and look at the content type.

```
var url = '/url/to/your/file.jpg',
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open('HEAD', url);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
    }
};
xhttp.send();
```